# Sculpting with Dynamic Topology, using Inflate Brush, blue Artifacts appear

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

[image: blue artifact]

I sculpted with Dyntypo enabled, but then there appeared those strange blue artifacts. If I use the smooth brush, it minimize the problem, but some artifacts stay.
Why does this happen? And how can I fix this?

Many thanks!
And happy modeling :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
I had strange bubbles of thausends of knoted vertices in the mesh, I don't know, how I have done this... At this stage i think it's the easiest to start new from scratch :D
But thanks a lot :)

Comment: There have been several bug reports posted on the tracker over the past couple years because of this.  Code-wise, nobody is sure how to fix it yet. :)

Comment: His brain exploded, its perfectly normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of bleed through from the inner faces, facing the opposite direction. The darker color indicates the Normals direction. Try to never have interior faces near the sculpting surface while sculpting. If the hair is a separate object, you can completely remove inner faces, as they serve no purpose.

[image: Sculpting Demonstration]

Notice that you will have to do this before you begin sculpting, as sculpting directly affects changes to the mesh. In order to salvage your mesh, you will have to just clean up as carefully as possible, using the *Smooth* brush and such tools.

[image: Sculpting repair]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I ended up with strange bubbles of thausends of tangled vertices in the mesh... I don't know how I have done this by sculpting O.O
But I will start from scratch for the hair!
Thanks again, you are a lifesaver :D

Comment: No problem! I think the reason that the many bubbles were forming is that the previous strokes had made the two sides approach each other, and had subdivided them using Dynotopo, making it possible for the next action to affect both sides. However, the reversed normals (tells which way a face is facing) mean that the opposite side goes **up** instead of down, thus they intersected.